# Do Kotlin Extension Functions declare member variables implicitly?

Tags: kotlin, this, extension-function

I have a data class `User`

```
data class User(name: String?, email: String?)
```

and I created an extension function to get the best identifier (name first, then email)

```
fun User.getBestIdentifier(): String {
    return when {
        !this.name.isNullOrBlank() -> this.name
        !this.email.isNullOrBlank() -> this.email
        else -> ""
}
```

But I noticed that in my IDE if I get rid of all of the `this` words, it still compiles and runs. Like:

```
fun User.getBestIdentifier(): String {
    return when {
        !name.isNullOrBlank() -> name
        !email.isNullOrBlank() -> email
        else -> ""
}
```

My conclusion was that Kotlin extension functions support member variables implicitly but I am not sure. Does anyone have any documentation of this phenomena or an explanation of why/how it happens?

Comment: You can always omit `this` anywhere there isn't ambiguity, not just in extension functions. `this` is only necessary when you need to distinguish members with matching names, like in a function where a parameter name matches a name in the class containing the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) state:

> The `this` keyword inside an extension function corresponds to the receiver object.

In your case, `User` is the receiver object and thus `this` refers to exactly that object.

Another reference can be found on [this site](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) which describes the `this` expression:

> In an extension function or a function literal with receiver `this` denotes the receiver parameter that is passed on the left-hand side of a dot.

Further:

> When you call a member function on `this`, you can skip the `this`.

Comment: "When you call a member function on this, you can skip the this." Or an extension function, or access a property, or an inner class...